# is there any way to index the hana adapted struct by its member name?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I have a hana defined struct, I knew I can iterate through it, but I wonder how can I index it by member name?

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
int main()
{
    struct Person {
        BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Person,
            (std::string, name),
            (int, age)
        );
    };
    Person john{"john Dow", 30};

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any hana tools allow me to do `get(john, "name")` and return `john Dow`?

Comment: If you found a solution, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is [at_key](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Searchable.html#ga3c1826aee6c6eb577810bb99c5c3e53d). we can use `hana::at_key(obj, key)`

Answer (score 1):

From scrolling through the Hana documentation examples, I found the following that may work for you:

```
hana::find(john, BOOST_HANA_STRING("name"))
```

Comment: It returns an optional<std::string>, so keep that in mind